# SQL Server stored procedure - error converting data type varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PostScheduledTasks] 
    @actualStart datetime = NULL, 
    @actualFinish datetime = NULL,
    @actualEndDate datetime = NULL,
    @UserDate1 datetime = NULL,
    @IsCompleted bit = 0,
    @PercentComplete float = 0.0,
    @UStmp varchar(10) = NULL,
    @SchedukeTaskID int = 0,
    @SortOrder int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE ScheduleTasks  
    SET ActualStart = @actualStart,
        ActualFinish = @actualFinish,
        ActualEndDate = @actualEndDate,
        UserDate1 = @UserDate1,
        IsCompleted = @IsCompleted,
        PercentComplete = @percentComplete,
        UStmp = @UStmp
    WHERE 
        ScheduleTaskID = @SchedukeTaskID
        AND SortOrder = @SortOrder
END
```

and when I try to execute it:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PostScheduledTasks]
        @actualStart = N'08-03-2016 8:00:00 AM',
        @actualFinish = N'08-03-2016 4:00:00 PM',
        @actualEndDate = N'08-03-2016 4:00:00 PM',
        @UserDate1 = N'27-01-2016 8:00:00 AM',
        @IsCompleted = 1,
        @PercentComplete = 1,
        @UStmp = N'jsuske',
        @SchedukeTaskID = 597295,
        @SortOrder = 19

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

I get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Comment: Check your ScheduleTasks table to make sure ActualStart, ActualFinish and ActualEndDate are actually datetime columns in the database.

Comment: It's failing on the `N'27-01-2016 8:00:00 AM'` entry -- SQL server is likely expects `MM/dd` when you use 12-hour time, not `dd-MM`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safest way is to provide dates as [ISO 8601](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) which is culture independent:

> yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
>
> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an international standard. Also, datetime values that are specified by using this format are unambiguous. Also, **this format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE settings.**

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PostScheduledTasks]
        @actualStart     = N'2016-03-08T08:00:00',
        @actualFinish    = N'2016-03-08T16:00:00',
        @actualEndDate   = N'2016-03-08T16:00:00',
        @UserDate1       = N'2016-01-27T08:00:00',
        @IsCompleted     = 1,
        @PercentComplete = 1,
        @UStmp           = N'jsuske',
        @SchedukeTaskID  = 597295,
        @SortOrder       = 19

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Or you have to check `SET LANGUAGE/DATEFORMAT` and provide date in correct format.

Comment: @user979331 Please try again, first version didn't have 0 before hour. My mistype :)