# How to run procedure passing data as nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not able to execute the procedure.
It is giving Error error when converting varchar datatype into datetime.

If I write without a procedure, it inserts as nvarchar

How can I test my procedure passing dates?

Financial.spInsertValidity 36168, '2021-10-14 14:43:07.530', '2021-10-20 14:43:07.530', 147, 1, 0, 'thiagocorrea@pedidoeletronico.com'

```
Create Procedure Financial.spInsertValidity(

    @idEmpresa bigint
,   @dtInicioVigencia datetime
,   @dtFimVigencia datetime
,   @idProduto int 
,   @qtdProduto int
,   @stPeriodoTolerancia bit
,   @User nvarchar(256)

)

As
Begin

Declare @Id bigint
Declare @ActiveUser nvarchar(5);
Declare @IdUser bigint;

Set @ActiveUser = Administrative.fnCheckActiveUser(@User);
Set @IdUser = Administrative.fnGetIdUser(@User)

if(@ActiveUser = 'false')
throw 51000, 'User not registered', 1;

Insert tb_vigencia_empresa(

    IdEmpresa
,   dtInicioVigencia
,   dtFimVigencia
,   stAtivo
,   idProduto
,   qtdProduto
,   stPeriodoTolerancia
,   CreatedBy
,   ChangedBy
,   CreationDate
,   ChangeDate
)
 Values(

    @IdEmpresa
,   @dtInicioVigencia
,   @dtFimVigencia
,   1
,   @idProduto
,   @qtdProduto
,   @stPeriodoTolerancia
,   @IdUser
,   @IdUser
,   SWITCHOFFSET (GetDate(), administrative.ReturnTimeZone(@User))
,   SWITCHOFFSET (GetDate(), administrative.ReturnTimeZone(@User))
)

Set @Id = @@Identity
Select @Id as Id

End
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server stored procedure - error converting data type varchar to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875138/sql-server-stored-procedure-error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have `set dateformat dmy;` in effect, e.g.:

```sql
set dateformat dmy;
exec spInsertValidity 36168, '2021-10-14 14:43:07.530', '2021-10-20 14:43:07.530', 147, 1, 0, 'thiagocorrea@pedidoeletronico.com';

Msg 8114 Level 16 State 5 Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to datetime.
```

Try using `mdy` or `ymd` instead, e.g.:

```sql
set dateformat mdy;
exec spInsertValidity 36168, '2021-10-14 14:43:07.530', '2021-10-20 14:43:07.530', 147, 1, 0, 'thiagocorrea@pedidoeletronico.com';
-- No error

set dateformat ymd;
exec spInsertValidity 36168, '2021-10-14 14:43:07.530', '2021-10-20 14:43:07.530', 147, 1, 0, 'thiagocorrea@pedidoeletronico.com';
-- No error
```

### Avoiding DATEFORMAT Issues

To avoid issues with the `DATEFORMAT` setting consider passing `datetime` type scalar variables into your stored procedure instead, and use `CONVERT` to populate them, e.g.:

```sql
set dateformat dmy;
declare @param1 datetime = convert(datetime, '2021-10-14 14:43:07.530', 121);
declare @param2 datetime = convert(datetime, '2021-10-20 14:43:07.530', 121);
exec spInsertValidity 36168, @param1, @param2, 147, 1, 0, 'thiagocorrea@pedidoeletronico.com';
-- No error
```

See the [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) documentation for the supported datetime style numbers and their formats.